# ios linker errors not found. QMIParser.dylib and gcrt1.o

Tags: ios, linker, clang

I am a new ios developer, I want to get images from video and cant do it.
I am getting linker errors after including all required frameworks. The following is the transcript for the received errors.

```
CompileC /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o MyPhotoApp/ViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/ucpr-lab1/Desktop/MyPhotoApp
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -iquote /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/MyPhotoApp-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/MyPhotoApp-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/MyPhotoApp-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/MyPhotoApp-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MyPhotoApp-Prefix-ewadaforutrycdbfrrwephbrlbxn/MyPhotoApp-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.dia -c /Users/ucpr-lab1/Desktop/MyPhotoApp/MyPhotoApp/ViewController.m -o /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o

/Users/ucpr-lab1/Desktop/MyPhotoApp/MyPhotoApp/ViewController.m:109:15: warning: unused variable 'image' [-Wunused-variable]
     UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
              ^
/Users/ucpr-lab1/Desktop/MyPhotoApp/MyPhotoApp/ViewController.m:189:6: warning: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:240:1: note: method 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' declared here
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 6_0);
^
/Users/ucpr-lab1/Desktop/MyPhotoApp/MyPhotoApp/ViewController.m:197:6: warning: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:240:1: note: method 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' declared here
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 6_0);
^
3 warnings generated.

Ld /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.app/MyPhotoApp normal i386
    cd /Users/ucpr-lab1/Desktop/MyPhotoApp
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/system -F/Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Intermediates/MyPhotoApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyPhotoApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework Accelerate -framework Accounts -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AdSupport -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework ExternalAccessory -framework GameKit /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/gcrt1.o -framework GLKit -framework GSS -framework iAd -framework ImageIO /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/lazydylib1.o -lAccessibility -lacmobileshim -lafc -larchive.2 -larchive -lAWDProtobuf -lAWDProtobufAirPlay -lAWDProtobufAPSD -lAWDProtobufBluetooth -lAWDProtobufCaptive -lAWDProtobufFacetime -lAWDProtobufFacetimeiMessage -lAWDProtobufGCK -lAWDProtobufLocation -lAWDProtobufSiri -lAWDProtobufTelephony -lAWDProtobufWifi -lAWDSupport -lAXSpeechManager -lbsm.0 -lbsm -lbz2.1.0 -lbz2 -lc++.1 -lc++ -lc++abi -lc -lcache -lcharset.1.0.0 -lcharset.1 -lcharset -lcommonCrypto -lcompiler_rt -lcopyfile -lcorecrypto -lCRFSuite -lCRFSuite0.12 -lcurses -ldbm -ldispatch -ldl -ldnsinfo -ldyld -ledit.2 -ledit.3.0 -ledit.3 -ledit -lexslt.0 -lexslt -lform.5.4 -lform -lgcc_s.1 -lgermantok -lH5Dynamic -liconv.2.4.0 -liconv.2 -liconv -licucore.A -licucore -linfo -lIOAccessoryManager -lIOKit.A -lIOKit -lipconfig -lipsec.A -lipsec -lkeymgr -llangid -llaunch -llaunchbuddy -llockdown -llzma.5 -llzma -lm -lmacho -lMatch.1 -lMatch -lmav_ipc_router_dynamic -lmecab_em -lmecabra -lmis -lMobileCheckpoint -lMobileGestalt -lncurses.5.4 -lncurses -lobjc.A -lobjc -lomadm -lpoll -lproc -lprotobuf -lpthread -lQLCharts -lremovefile -lresolv.9 -lresolv -lrpcsvc -lsandbox.1 -lsandbox -lsp -lsqlite3.0 -lsqlite3 -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lstdc++.6 -lstdc++ -lSystem.B -lSystem -lsystem_blocks -lsystem_c -lsystem_dnssd -lsystem_info -lsystem_kernel -lsystem_m -lsystem_network -lsystem_notify -lsystem_sandbox -lTelephonyIOKitDynamic -ltidy.A -ltidy -lType2Streamer -lunwind -lUSBControlDynamic -lutil -lutil1.0 -lWAPI -lxml2.2 -lxml2 -lxpc -lxslt.1 -lxslt -lz.1.1.3 -lz.1.2.5 -lz.1 -lz -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MediaToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework PassKit /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/QMIParser.dylib -framework QuartzCore -framework QuickLook -framework Security -framework Social -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Twitter -framework CPlusTest -framework DTPerformanceSession -framework InterfaceBuilderKit -framework SenTestingKit -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -o /Users/ucpr-lab1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPhotoApp-aekdtunmahwzdadxhzuidczidlvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyPhotoApp.app/MyPhotoApp

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/gcrt1.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/QMIParser.dylib'
```